# How can I merge the columns from two tables into one output

Tags: office365, ms-access-2010

I receive assay values from multiple laboratories. I import them all into a mass Access table called "sample". within this "sample" are dozens of headers that allow for the collation of information that is newly imported, and also significant legacy values. For example:

| Si_% | Si_pct | Si_ppm | Si_ppb | Au_% | Au_pct | Au_ppm | Au_ppb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 63 | 0.063 | 0.5 | 500 | 0.5 |  |  |

(with values beneath the headers. Some are null spaces due to different requirements for previous or new laboratory assays)

[image: example of ppm and % in same table]

I wish to clean up the data with a new table that automatically updates imported values from the bulk "sample" table, into separate tables that streamline the headers.

I want the new tables to be called "samples_%", "samples_ppm", samples_ppb" etc. With the index ID also coming across.

I then wish to automate this process in a macro after each import from the laboratory .csv / .xlsx such that when the "sample" has been updated, running the macro will automatically update these new tables also. Can anyone help?

I have tried to generate queries that would assist but I fee I am heading down the wrong track (see below fail).

[image]

Comment: Do you _absolutely have_ to use Access?  (and Access 2010?!?)

Comment: Apologies  - incorrect tag. I am using 365.
New tag added, with old kept to contextualise above response.

Comment: There is likely room to move to another database system down the line (datashed the most likely candidate)

Comment: The reason I bring it up is because Access (even Access in Office 2021) is basically frozen-in-time since Access 2002, and its archaic SQL dialect is so anemic it's painful to use (and the SQL editor built-in to Access is horribly broken, even a stray tab (`\t`) character breaks it, _fml_). Even using SQLite would be a massive improvement.

Comment: A fair consideration! This is a weekend project with the tools I have at hand. 

However, I will enthusiastically look into (after addressing this issue) if there exists an open-source alternative database suite. Anything you could recommend as an interim for this project?

Comment: Well, namely SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/index.html - you'll need a separate frontend, such as https://sqlitestudio.pl/ or https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: _"I want the new tables to be called "samples_%", "samples_ppm", samples_ppb" etc. With the index ID also coming across."_ - you can't use punctuation and symbols in table-names without having to escape them, consider using a name like "`samples_perc`" instead of `samples_%`.

Comment: That is an easy change to make at the start! I am happy for the table titles to be "*_pct", rather than "*_%"
I can make the destination table "sample_pct" - my challenge now is coming to grips within this older software. Cheers for the assist in advance!

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, you want to put all of the percentage columns into the `samples_%` table, and all of the PPM measurements into the `samples_ppm` table? ...but why do you want to do that though? ...that would be a denormalization.

Comment: Also, are the PPM values and percentage values equivalent to each other - or otherwise such that one is derived from the other?

Comment: We have multiple values coming in, and there are legacy values that can be requested also.  These are in multiple formats (%, pct, percen, percentage, etc) I have generated a bulk source that will take everything, and I am attempting to handle a specific request to have subordinate tables that are "less messy". 

Some elements arrive with ppm, ppb. Others will have percentage representation. Due to the almost 65 years of assays I need to account for several "nouns" for each dataset. 

A macro that pulls all values of "%, perc, etc" into the newly titles samples_pct is the immediate goal.

Comment: ppm and percentages can be correlated in some scenarios.